# Using Dynamic URL for PayPal Redirect

Tags: php, dynamic, web, paypal, payment

I have an orders form, in which the following variables could be chosen: price, currency, quantity (+ others). The form is submitted through jquery:  $("#paypal_form").submit();

Everything is fine and the transaction goes on normally, but in the end PayPal doesn't redirect to the specified URL in the form. Could you let me know what the correct setting for PayPal is, because in PayPal's options the only choice is to fill in a URL (otherwise it won't allow you to set the Auto Return setting), but my URL is dynamic and is changed based on the transaction ID. It looks something like this: `<input type="hidden" name="return" value="myReturnUrl.php?OrderID=88273882717A72734">`

Here is the form itself (fields are filled in with js):

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" id="paypal_form">
<p> 
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@mail.com" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Citation Building" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="id=0" />
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="Business_BuyNow_WPS_SE" /> 
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="Buy Now" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's 'return' as you have it right now, but it needs to be an absolute URL. E.g.;

`<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970910/using-dynamic-url-for-paypal-redirect">`

Comment: Thanks, Robert. My URL is also absolute:

    $('input[name="amount"]').val(price.data('price')); $('input[name="return"]').val('http://www.domain.com/service-name/id='+data.id); $("#paypal_form").submit();

Comment: Whoops. Http:// is present in the original, I just missed it in the example above.

Comment: Can you upload an example of the form as you have it now please? jsFiddle is fine.

Comment: I am kind of reluctant to provide the direct link, but here is a screenshot to the relevant part of the form: http://alfa.kachi-snimka.info/images-2013/rgh1375382851c.jpg

Should any option inside the PayPal account be set in a different way? Just the return field doesn't work. Everything else seems to be fine.

Thanks again for your help.